# Meteor run ios --verbose

Tags: javascript, ios, node.js, meteor

when i try to run meteor todos example app in ios, by command

```
sudo meteor run ios --verbose
```

(The reason i use sudo because without sudo, it displays eaccess error, permission denied error)

Then after using above command with sudo i get following error:

```
** BUILD SUCCEEDED **
2014-12-10 17:55:17.475 ios-sim[4120:60148] stderrPath: /Users/black_monk/meteor_examples/todos/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/ios/cordova/console.log
2014-12-10 17:55:17.476 ios-sim[4120:60148] stdoutPath: /Users/black_monk/meteor_examples/todos/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/ios/cordova/console.log
Session could not be started: Error Domain=DTiPhoneSimulatorErrorDomain Code=2 "Simulator session timed out." UserInfo=0x7ffcbb4103c0 {NSLocalizedDescription=Simulator session timed out.}
Command finished with error code 1: /Users/black_monk/meteor_examples/todos/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/ios/cordova/run --emulator
Error: /Users/black_monk/meteor_examples/todos/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/ios/cordova/run: Command failed with exit code 1
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (/Users/black_monk/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.36.690ab6++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:135:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:755:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:822:5)

Could not start the app in the iOS simulator.
Try running again with the --verbose option.
```

It only display this message i am not sure what is the problem. I'm trying to get meteor run on mobile but one way or another it only fails, and im not sure why. I tried same on android, same EACCESS error.

All the SDKs are installed. No guide to learn from to clue whatsoever.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to use `sudo` to run anything in meteor. If you do, it sounds like you ran the meteor install command as `sudo`? If that is the case, try uninstalling meteor and reinstalling it as your normal user. It looks like you are encountering a permission error between meteor, cordova and the IOS simulator.

Comment: did that too, is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

Did it,

changed all the directories to permission 777

sudo find /Users/black_monk/meteor_examples/todos/.meteor/local/ -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;

and all the files inside it to 777 as well

sudo find /Users/black_monk/meteor_examples/todos/.meteor/local/ -type f -exec chmod 777 {} \;